# XPath for table rows (tr) based on position and cell (td) count?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I need an XPath for a document like this:

```html
-tr
--td
--td
--td
--td
--td
-tr
--td
--td
--td
--td
--td
-tr
--td   <-- here is only one td inside the tr. I need only the ones above this tr
-tr
--td
--td
--td
--td
--td
-tr
--td
--td
--td
--td
--td
-tr
--td
```

Like in the example, I need only the `tr`'s from first to the `tr` with only the one `td`. The other `tr`'s after that should also NOT be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Assuming there's only a single `tr` that has one `td` child...*</sup>

This XPath,

```
//tr[count(td)=1]/preceding-sibling::tr
```

will select all `tr` siblings elements prior to the `tr` that has a single `td` child.

There is no `preceding-sibling-or-self` axis, but you could concatenate via `|`:

```
//tr[count(td)=1] | //tr[count(td)=1]/preceding-sibling::tr
```

to include the `tr` with a single `td` child too.

Comment: wow nice! That works fine. Just another question concerning this: is it possible to combine it and exxlude the first 3 Tr's?

Comment: `//tr[count(td)=1]/preceding-sibling::tr[position() != 1 and position() != 2 and position() != 3]`

Comment: i tried this, but it excludes that LAST 3 of them. I need the FIRST ones..

Comment: `//tr[count(td)=1]/preceding-sibling::tr[position() != last() and position() != last() - 1 and position() != last() - 2]`

Comment: Note that the position of the `tr` selected along the `preceding-sibling` axis will be ordered such that `position() = 1` will be the *closest* to the starting `tr` and `position() = last()` will be the *farthest*.